# react app works locally but not when deployed on server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code block that works perfectly fine on my local development environment, but when I run npm run build and host my app on a static server, I get an error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addFilter')"

I cannot understand why a function will work fine on my local server, but won't work when It's in production mode/on a static site?

```
class Filters extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {

        super(props)
        this.state = {
            currentCampaign: props.currentCampaign, uid: props.uid, FiltersOpen: false, filters: [], FilterGenderMale: false, provinceSet: false, filtersActive: false, MarketingPlanModal: false, ThankYou: false
            , BusinessName: '', IndustryName: '', OnlineSearch: '', Interests: '', WebLink: ''
        }
        this.loadFilters()
        this.addFilter = this.addFilter.bind(this)
        this.FilterItem = this.FilterItem.bind(this)
    }

    async addFilter(FilterValue) {
        ////Do some stuff
    }

    FilterItem({ active, name }) {
        if (active) {
            return <div style={{ width: "100%" }} ><button className='buttonStyle' style={{ width: "100%" }} onClick={this.addFilter.bind(this, name)}>{name}</button> </div>
        }
    }

    ReturnFiltersOpenViews = () => {
        return <div>
            {isDesktopOrLaptop &&
                <div>
                   
                                        <this.FilterItem active={GenderFemaleView} name={"Gender: Female"} />
                                        <this.FilterItem active={GenderMaleView} name={"Gender: Male"} />
                                        <this.FilterItem active={TwentyView} name={"Age: 20-24"} />
                                        <this.FilterItem active={TwentyFiveView} name={"Age: 25-29"} />
                                        <this.FilterItem active={ThirtyView} name={"Age: 30-34"} />
                                        <this.FilterItem active={ThirtyFiveView} name={"Age: 35-39"} />
                                        <this.FilterItem active={FortyView} name={"Age: 40-44"} />
                                        <this.FilterItem active={FortyFiveView} name={"Age: 45-49"} />
                                        <this.FilterItem active={FiftyView} name={"Age: 50-54"} />
                                        <this.FilterItem active={FiftyFiveView} name={"Age: 55-60"} />
                                   
                </div>
            }
            {isTabletOrMobile &&
                <div>

                   

                                <div className='FilterMobileOptions'>
                                    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
                                        <div style={{ width: "49%" }}>
                                            <this.FilterItem active={GenderFemaleView} name={"Gender: Female"} style={{ width: "40%" }} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div style={{ width: "49%", paddingLeft: "2%" }}>
                                            <this.FilterItem active={GenderMaleView} name={"Gender: Male"} />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
                                        <div style={{ width: "49%" }}>
                                            <this.FilterItem active={TwentyView} name={"Age: 20-24"} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div style={{ width: "49%", paddingLeft: "2%" }}>
                                            <this.FilterItem active={TwentyFiveView} name={"Age: 25-30"} />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
                                        <div style={{ width: "49%" }}>
                                            <this.FilterItem active={ThirtyView} name={"Age: 30-34"} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div style={{ width: "49%", paddingLeft: "2%" }}>
                                            <this.FilterItem active={ThirtyFiveView} name={"Age: 35-39"} />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
                                        <div style={{ width: "49%" }}>
                                            <this.FilterItem active={FortyView} name={"Age: 40-44"} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div style={{ width: "49%", paddingLeft: "2%" }}>
                                            <this.FilterItem active={FortyFiveView} name={"Age: 45-49"} />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
                                        <div style={{ width: "49%" }}>
                                            <this.FilterItem active={FiftyView} name={"Age: 50-54"} />
                                        </div>
                                        <div style={{ width: "49%", paddingLeft: "2%" }}>
                                            <this.FilterItem active={FiftyFiveView} name={"Age: 55-60"} />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                      
                // </div>
            }

        </div>
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.FiltersOpen) {
            return (
                <this.ReturnFiltersOpenViews />

            )
        }
    }
}
export default Filters;
  //export default MyMap;
```

Arrow functions created more problems and I want to stay away from using it.